# Locally build IPA is working fine but IPA build from Azure DevOps Pipelines are unable to Load / crash after installation

Tags: ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ipa

I am facing an issue, while prepare the ios IPA build locally through xcode, IPA works fine without any issue. At the same time when I prepare the ios IPA build through Azure pipelines (Azure hosted macos), the generated IPA is not working, even app is not loading after installation.(with same repo code).

I've tried with below multiple options in azure pipeline..but still unable to open/load the app after installation.
macOS-11.6.8 + xcode v13.2.1, macOS-12 + xcode v13.3, macOS-12 + xcode v13.2.1, macOS-12 + xcode v13.4.1, Below is my YAML Pipeline.

```
trigger:
  - none
resources:
  - repo: self
variables:
  - group: groupname
jobs:
  - job: build
    timeoutInMinutes: 180
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macos-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
      clean: true
    - task: NodeTool@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Install Node'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.0.0' # you can use your desired version here
    - script: yarn install
      displayName: Install Dependencies
    
    - task: ios-bundle-version@1
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Bump iOS version'
      inputs:
        sourcePath: 'packages/abcproject/ios/abcmobile/Info.plist'
        versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
        versionCode: '$(Build.BuildId)'
        versionName: '$(NEW_VERSION)'
        printFile: false
    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: Install Apple Certificate
      inputs:
        certSecureFile: 'abc.p12'
        certPwd: '$(p12password)'
        keychain: 'temp'
        deleteCert: true
    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Install Apple Provisioning Profile'
      inputs:
        provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
        provProfileSecureFile: 'abc_qa.mobileprovision'
        removeProfile: true
    - task: CocoaPods@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Install CocoaPods'
      inputs:
        workingDirectory: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/packages/abcproject/ios'
    - task: Xcode@5
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Build IPA'
      inputs:
        actions: 'build'
        configuration: 'Qa'
        sdk: 'iphoneos'
        scheme: 'abcQa'
        xcWorkspacePath: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/packages/abcproject/ios/abcmobile.xcworkspace'
        packageApp: true
        exportPath: 'output/$(SDK)/$(Configuration)'
        exportMethod: 'enterprise'
        signingOption: 'manual'
        signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
        provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
        Contents: |
          **/*.ipa
          **/*.dSYM/**
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        overWrite: true
        cleanTargetFolder: true
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: iOSBuild'
      inputs:
        ArtifactName: iOSBuild
```

Comment: Getting below error if trying to upload IPA to VS App Center.
2022-08-27T06:44:00.1876820Z ##[error]Error: Loading release id failed: A problem occured while extracting your app. (Correlation ID: 3500acbb-165f-4b02-87bf-845044945fae)

Comment: was this resolved ever?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this error ?